# Why (Im) is gross(before personal tax-BPT) rate of return(ROR) by saver?It should be net ROR & APT, as SS' curve is after personal tax is imposed

Tags: public-economics, opportunity-cost

[![the  image was taken from public finance book by Musgrave and Musgrave
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMTdD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMTdD.png)Pave 156(fig. 9.5)

Comment: After being imposed personal tax why the author said SS' is before personal tax.